# Unable to setup Twitter auth for React Native app. Error: Unconfirmed callback

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, twitter

I have a trouble with that callbacks with Twitter.

I have React Native crossplatform app. Now I'm setting Android's part. There is needed to make some operations to set Twitter Auth. One of is set callback url.

I have Twitter App inside their website called SunyaInnov . I'd been generated consumers keys (both, as expected). Set up callback url there to https://www.google.com.

Inside app I have this:

-AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.foodilog"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:largeHeap="true"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
    </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data android:scheme="foodilog" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="**************************"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

-`login.js` file where callback invokes:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    Image,
    Button,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Navigator,
    Dimensions,
    DeviceEventEmitter,
    NativeModules,
    requireNativeComponent,
    Platform,
    AsyncStorage,
    Linking,
    ActivityIndicator
} from 'react-native';
import CheckBox from 'react-native-icon-checkbox';
import { twitter } from 'react-native-simple-auth'
export default class LoginPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            agree: false,
            isLoading: true
        };
    }
_twitterSignIn() {
    if (this.state.agree) {`console.log("trying to auth with twitter")
        twitter({
          appId: API.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
          appSecret: API.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
          callback: 'foodilog://authorize',
        }).then((info) => {
        console.log(info)
        const { authToken, authTokenSecret } = info;
          if (authToken && authTokenSecret) {
            AsyncStorage.setItem('CurrentSocialLogin', 'twitter');
            AsyncStorage.setItem('FoodilogTwitterToken', authToken);
            AsyncStorage.setItem('FoodilogTwitterTokenSecret', authTokenSecret);
            this.dispatchLogin(API.TWITTER_LOGIN_URL, authToken, authTokenSecret);
          }
          // info.user - user details from the provider
          // info.credentials - tokens from the provider
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
          // error.code
          // error.description
        });
}
```

It's only part of JavaScript file that concerned to signin with twitter.

Problem showed for me is:

> Error: Unconfirmed callback.

How can I figure out about how to setup that callback? What have to be on protocol place and host place inside callback.

Also notice: I use react-native-simple-auth package to auth with twitter (I think it's easiest way to auth and have anything necessary). If you have decisions about this let me know also.

Comment: I used https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-native-oauth for signin with twitter. It works very well.

Comment: @hannanessay bt what the app name I should paste inside... I know react-native-oauth... There is an method called `const manager = new OAuthManager('{what I should paste here}')` for twitter auth?
Name that is inside twitter apps menu above (Big'n'Bold Literals) is SunyaInnov

Comment: Yes, it should be the name that you used to create when you registered on  https://apps.twitter.com/ (Screenshot: https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HtVOyP9.png)

Comment: @hannanessay Thanks for helping me now) 
I have at least this unanswered questions. In my manifest activity in the callback url scheme I should only paste lowercased name of my twitter app (eg "sunyainnov")?
So the last... Inside react-native component its easy to add that new OAuthManager with following argument ("synuainnov") also.. Or something else/additional to setup cb url? no need to add suffixes or prefixes to name inside both of files?

Comment: @hannanessay , Also, do you know, how to correctly import this package inside react-native code. what to import? Cause here inside react-native-oauth guide nothing said about what and how to import inside js code.

Comment: Have a look at a sample app i had made around twitter. https://github.com/HannanShaik/TwitterApp

Comment: @hannanessay Thanks you so much) If your not against, I`ll fork it for my learning needs.
Only ONE very valuable question I need to ask you: What you wrote inside your twitter app "HannaTwitterApp" in settings Callback URL? I have any idea what should be wrote here... People said very variable things about this. What you wrote in this case (for your twitter app)?

Comment: it was a dummy domain url. Yes you can fork.

Answer (score 1):

Do you refer at twitter's settings?
//
Don’t use localhost as a callback URL
Instead of using localhost, please use a custom host locally or http(s)://127.0.0.1.

Make sure to add these if you are using Twitter Kit
If you use Twitter Kit for iOS or Android, you will have to use the following callback URLs:

Android - twittersdk://
iOS - twitterkit-CONSUMERKEY://

I recommend you use react-native-twitter-signin